# How can I use createStackNavigator (React Navigation) in React Native while using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I am writing an app using React Native and TypeScript and I use React Navigation for routing.
In the example project I downloaded they use `StackNavigator({...})` in order to create the navigator, but when I do `npm start` I see a warning stating that `StackNavigator` is deprecated and that I should use `createStackNavigator` instead. `createStackNavigator` is also the function I've seen in online tutorials.

The problem is that when using `createStackNavigator` I get an error:

```
[ts] Module '".../.../..."' has no exported member 'createStackNavigator'.
```

I checked and the `index.d.ts` file in the path indeed doesn't have such a member. I tries `npm install @types/react-navigation@latest` but that didn't help too.

What can I do so I could use `createStackNavigator`? Or should I resort to the deprecated `StackNavigator`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type definition files from @types is not up to date, and will probably not be updated anymore since TypeScript support will be added to the react-navigation library soon.

You can find more information on this [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/4075) and also an up-to-date version of the type definition file (scroll almost all the way to the bottom). Just copy / paste that snippet over to the index.d.ts file in your node_modules/@types/react-navigation/ folder. This will allow you to use createStackNavigator and others.